# Cant figure out how to code this in php

Tags: php

I am trying to `$_GET` some variables that a user may enter (busy making a basic web-server):

```
$users= strval($_GET['user']);
$price= intval($_GET['price']);
$productID= intval($_GET['productid']);
```

This is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user` = '" . $user . "' AND `price` <= " . $price . " AND `productID` = " . $productID;
```

(something like this)

Given this theoretical link:

```
www.example.com/api.php?price=300
```

And don't use the rest of the GET (user and productID) will automatically be filled with either 0 or '' (int/string).

So I thought I could use an `if` statement:

```
if(price == 0){
   // change the query without the price as WHERE
}
```

But what if I have combinations of price and productID or productID and user as variables.

What is the best way to handle this? Maybe it's a stupid question but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combined IF statements to build the appropriate query using the variables if they are supplied (and ignoring them if not)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1"; // WHERE 1 means "return all rows from table"

if ( isset( $_GET['price'] ) ){ // Only if price variable is set
    $query .= " AND price <= '{$_GET['price']}'"; // Restrict results by price
}

if ( isset( $_GET['user'] ) ){ // Only if user variable is set
    $query .= " AND user LIKE '{$_GET['user']}'"; // Restrict results by user
}

if ( isset( $_GET['productID'] ) ){ // Only if user variable is set
    $query .= " AND productID = '{$_GET['productID']}'"; // Restrict results by productID
}
```

Comment: so .= adds text to the query.. nice did not know that, but the isset() method...wil that work because if 0 is already in it or '' its automaticly set right ?

Comment: @user1692174: as far as I know, when a variable isn't set (with the *GET* method) it is *null*, not `0`.

Comment: it worked great! the isset checks the function if its not set it doesnt do anything..tnx! now i need to search on security hehe

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to make query string correctly, concatenating price clause when it is set.

```
$query = "select * from table where user = $user" . ($price ? " AND price <= $price" : "") . " AND productID = $productID";
```

Your english is poor, we are brazilians o/

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = $_GET['user'] || "";
$price = $_GET['price'] || 0;
$productID = $_GET['productid'] || 0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1";

$query .= (isset($_GET['user'))?"AND user = '{$users}'";
$query .= (isset($_GET['price'))?"AND price <= '{$price}'";
$query .= (isset($_GET['productid'))?"AND productID = '{$productID}'";
```

In case you want to use the variables for something else. This sets the values to `0` or `""` (empty string) if they aren't set in the `$_GET` data.

Comment: if you set 0 or "" the results of the query will be affected, so i cant set 0 or ""